# How can i detect DOM prepared and all attributes set

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, typescript, jquery-events

I have next html structure:

```
<div id="controls">    
    <div class="action" data-action="controller/action1" data-view="view1">...</div>
    <div class="action" data-action="controller/action1" data-view="view2">...</div>
    <div class="action" data-action="controller/action2" data-view="view1">...</div>
    <div class="action" data-action="controller/action2" data-view="view2">...</div>
     ...e.t.c.
</div>
```

In typeScript i try to get data-attributes and build ajax query:

```
$('#controls').off('click').on('click','.action',(e) => {
       var $element = $(e.target),
            action = $element.data('action'),
            view = $element.data('view');

        if(!action)
            return this.sendNotification(false,'Setup action in config');
        if(!view)
            return this.sendNotification(false,'Setup view in config');

        // Ajax request and other logic 
});
```

Also i have function that update part of the page (include div blocks in start of topic)

```
private updateActionsBlock() {
   $.get(location.href, (html) => {
       $('#controls').html($(html).find('#controls'));
            this.init();
   });
}
```

**PROBLEM**

If user has troubles with Internet connection or slow computer (probably browser hasn't enough RAM) - after using `updateActionBlock()` a few second impossible to get data attributes from `$('.action')`. These become undefined.

**Question**

How can i disable clicking on `$('.action');` before DOM ready ?

I hope that it is possible to do without `setTimeout`

Comment: Either only run `updateActionsBlock()` after document.ready has fired, or hide the elements and fade them in on document.ready. I don't see how that is actually your problem though, as the delegated event should be bound *long* before the AJAX request completes

Comment: Unfortunately i need to use `updateActionBlock` after each ajax request processed by `.action` clicking.
`document.ready`, `document.DOMContentLoaded` works only in page initialisation

Comment: Ok, but my point is that the delegated event handler is already bound, so there is no way that an element can be clicked without the event being triggered.

Comment: Event triggered. But it's looks like target element hasn't data attributes.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/k2432b4r/. Note that I did have to manually add the `active` class to the elements though, as that's missing in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in DOM.

```
$('#controls').off('click').on('click','.action',(e) => {
       var $element = $(e.target),
            action = $element.data('action'),
            view = $element.data('view');

        if(!action)
            return this.sendNotification(false,'Setup action in config');
        if(!view)
            return this.sendNotification(false,'Setup view in config');

        // Ajax request and other logic 
});
```

Some times, when i click on `.action`  i had wrong element in `e.target`. Instead of `<div class='action'>...</div>` i obtained inner elements.

So when i change `e.target` to `e.currentTarget` bug was fixed.